# Want to insert two tables in one method ASP.NET web api 2

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, postman

I tried the below code to insert data to two tables but it inserts only for one table and the second table's data is not inserting it's just inserting the Tstamp column only. I tried to POST data from POSTMON.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostOrder(CustomerOrder customerOrder)
    {
        using (GeoContext context = new GeoContext())
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var order = context.CustomerOrders.Add(customerOrder);
            context.CustomerOrders.Add(order);
            order.Tstamp = DateTime.Now;

            OrderProduct prod = new OrderProduct();

            var product = context.OrderProducts.Add(prod);
            context.OrderProducts.Add(product);
            order.OrderID = product.OrderID;
            product.Tstamp = DateTime.Now;

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return Ok(new { Message = "Order placed" });
    }
```

Below JSON values that i tried to insert from POSTMAN

```
{
"CustomerID":2,
"OrderNo":4,
"TotalPrice":50.00,
"Tstamp":"2021-03-31",
"Product":"Apple",
"Price":5,
"Quantity":10
}
```

CustomerOrder Class

```
 public partial class CustomerOrder
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public CustomerOrder()
    {
        this.OrderProducts = new HashSet<OrderProduct>();
    }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OrderNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Tstamp { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<OrderProduct> OrderProducts { get; set; }
}
```

OrderProduct Class

```
 public partial class OrderProduct
{
    public int OrderProductID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Tstamp { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerOrder CustomerOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show CustomerOrder and OrderProduct classes pls?

Comment: @Sergey Edit the question. you can check now

Comment: You never do set the `prod` properties? you have `OrderProduct prod = new OrderProduct();` but nothing like `prod.OrderID = ??; prod.Product="?? `

Comment: @RuiCaramalho How to pass data from two tables from POSTMON?

Comment: @Sergey gave you the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create and fill  an OrderProduct instance and add it to CustomerOrder   in order to add a record to OrderProduct table.

```
{
    "customerID": 2,
    "orderNo": 4,
    "tstamp": "2021-03-31",
    "orderProducts": [
        {
        "Product":"Apples",
        "Price":5,
        "Quantity":10 
        }
    ]
}
```

Fix the action for a Postman:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostOrder(CustomerOrder customerOrder)
    {
        using (GeoContext context = new GeoContext())
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

          double? orderSum = 0.0;
            foreach (var product in customerOrder.OrderProducts)
            {
                product.Tstamp = DateTime.Now;
                orderSum += ( (double)product.Price) * product.Quantity;
            }
             context.CustomerOrders.Add(customerOrder);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return Ok(new { Message = "Order placed" });
    }
```